# Add optgroup to dropdown created dynamically using REST, jQuery and Boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, rest, sharepoint

This is my very first project using Bootstrap and I'm pretty new with jQuery also, so I hope this question is not too simple for some of you. I have this drop-down I have created pulling data from SharePoint using REST and Ajax. This part works great.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var requestUri = "blah-blah/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('AD_DB')/items?select=Title,State";
var requestHeaders = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function (i, result) {
            var ItemCaseNumber = result.Title;
            var ItemState = result.State;
            $('#myList').append('<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">' + ItemCaseNumber + '</a></li>');

        });
    },
    error: function ajaxError(response) {
        alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
    }
});
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1" id="myList"></ul>
```

As I mentioned the drop-down gets populated as expected, but this is the issue. Is there a way to create optgroups based on the values of the variable "ItemState", which contains the States in the SharePoint list? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't have `optgroups` by default but it does use `dropdown-headers`. You can always switch to the [bootstrap-select plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) if you really want opt-groups.

Anyway, this is an example with dropdown-headers:

```js
var results = [{ State: 'AZ', Title: 'Case 1234'},
               { State: 'GA', Title: 'Case 4212'},
               { State: 'IA', Title: 'Case 23332'},
               { State: 'LA', Title: 'Case 2221' },
               { State: 'KS', Title: 'Case 4432' },
               { State: 'MD', Title: 'Case 2882'},
               { State: 'KS', Title: 'Case 1022' },
               { State: 'GA', Title: 'Case 1111' }];

// Sort results by State field. Uses the compareStates function below
results.sort(compareStates);

var lastState = '';
$.each(results, function (i, result) {
    var ItemCaseNumber = result.Title;
    var ItemState = result.State;

    // Add new header for each state 
    if (ItemState != lastState) {
      
        // Don't add a divider line if this is the first state in the dropdown
        if (i>0) {
            $('#myList').append('<li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>');
        }
      
        lastState = ItemState;
        $('#myList').append('<li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">'+ItemState+'</li>');
    }
    
    $('#myList').append('<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">' + ItemCaseNumber + '</a></li>');
});

function compareStates(a,b) {
  if (a.State < b.State)
     return -1;
  if (a.State > b.State)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1" id="myList"></ul>
</div>
```